# Power mode and program stm32 device

Tags: stm32, low-power

I'm studying about STM32 low power modes, and after program the device with `__Wfi` instruction I cant program another firmware in the device, I tried to use the STM utility to erase the code, but it show that the flash had write protection.

The first error that show is :

```
adapter speed: 24000 kHz

adapter_nsrst_delay: 100

Info : clock speed 24000 kHz

Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v34 API v2 SWIM v7 VID 0x0483 PID 0x3748

Info : using stlink api v2

Info : Target voltage: 3.192646

Error: init mode failed (unable to connect to the target)

in procedure 'program' 

in procedure 'init' called at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 495

in procedure 'ocd_bouncer'

** OpenOCD init failed **

shutdown command invoked
```

After a search, I found that I can get the firmware putting the `boot0` in VCC, so I did this, and the follow error was shown:

```
** Programming Started **

auto erase enabled

Info : device id = 0x10076413

Info : flash size = 512kbytes

Error: stm32x device protected

Error: failed erasing sectors 0 to 0

embedded:startup.tcl:476: Error: ** Programming Failed **
```

My board has a stm32f407vet6 processor. I'm using a ST-LinkV2 clone, for download and debug purposes.

Comment: STM32's do have a habit of locking themselves for odd reasons.  You probably need to run the unprotect sequence which includes a full power cycle.  Because I/O's can leak power in, it's generally best to disconnect everything when you do the power cycle.

Comment: Im begginer with arm development so i dont know what is this. Is it a new firmware that a have to download? I dont find any material related to this.

Comment: Unprotecting is an operation of a tool like OpenOCD or its competitors, which must be followed by a complete power cycle for which it is best to remove all connections to the board.

Answer (score -1):

For those who face the same problem, i solved this using st-link utility

1)First go to settings and change the connection setting to jtag.

2)Upgrade de firmware, change back to SWD.

3)Go to option bytes, put Read Out Protection in Level 0 and unselect all sectors(this will disable the protection and allow the flash to be erased).

After some research i found that "low power modes disable the debugger and some other parts of the circuitry that i try to communicate with" (Author: clive1, in https://community.st.com/s/ )